# Programmatically add properties on class initialization

Tags: python-2.7, properties

I want a class that should get a list of property names on initialization and than create these properties. All properties should use the same getter and setter methods (e.g. for validation).

I've already tried the following, but it does not work as expected:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,props):
        for prop in props:
            setattr(self,prop, property(self.get,self.set))

    def get(self,*args):
        # somehow get the value
        return 'get: ' + ','.join(args)

    def set(self,*args):
        # somehow save the value
        return 'set: ' + ','.join(args)

f = Foo(['foo_test'])
print f.foo_test
# output: <property object at 0x028650C0>
print type(f.foo_test)
# output: <type 'property'>
f.foo_test = 5
# no output
print type(f.foo_test)
# output: <type 'int'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did it. What I did not know before was that you have to use the property()-function on **class**-level, not on instance-level. Here's my code:

```
def get(obj, attr):
    print 'get: ' + ','.join(map(str,[obj, attr]))
    return getattr(obj,'__' + attr)

def set(obj, attr, val):
    print 'set: ' + ','.join(map(str,[obj, attr, val]))
    setattr(obj,'__' + attr,val)

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,attrs=None):
        for attr in attrs:
            setattr(self.__class__,'__' + attr, None)
            prop =  property(lambda obj,attr=attr: get(obj,attr),
                             lambda obj,val,attr=attr: set(obj,attr,val))            
            setattr(self.__class__,attr, prop)

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self,['bar_test1','bar_test2'])

b = Bar()
print b.bar_test1
# output:
# get: <__main__.Bar object at 0x02859310>,bar_test1
# None
b.bar_test1 = 5
# output:
# set: <__main__.Bar object at 0x02859310>,bar_test1,5
print b.bar_test1
# output:
# get: <__main__.Bar object at 0x02859310>,bar_test1
# 5
print b.bar_test2
# output:
# get: <__main__.Bar object at 0x02859310>,bar_test2
# None
```